# cron job is not working in ruby on rails in production mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, cron, scheduled-tasks

Cron job is not working in rails 3. I am using whenever gem Here is the code that I am using.

schedule.rb file

```
every 1.hours do
    command "cd /home/me/my_app/current"
    rake "thinking_sphinx:index RAILS_ENV=production"
end

every 1.day, :at => '12.01 am' do
   command "cd /home/me/my_app/current"
   rake "messages_counter_for_user_and_group RAILS_ENV=production"
   command "cd /home/me/my_app/current"
   runner "RAILS_ENV=production  User.update_all(:daily_message_count => 0)"  
end
```

From capistrano deploy script:-

```
task :long do
transaction do
  cron_tab_activate
end

task:cron_tab_activate, :roles=>:app do
 send(run_method, "cd #{current_path} && RAILS_ENV=#{stage}  whenever --update-crontab test ")
end
```

I am using rvm. Ruby 1.9.2, Rails 3.0.10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using custom capistrano tasks I would suggest to load capistrano tasks supplied by whenever gem.

Add to **deploy.rb**:

```
require 'whenever/capistrano'
```